# Can I store and call regex in variables for later use?

Tags: php, regex

I plan on storing regular expression codes in a database, but not sure how to get them from a variable to function.

Any advise?

```
$i = "([wx])([yz])" 
$j = "[^A-Za-z0-9]" 
$k= "([A-Z]{3}|[0-9]{4})"

    //Wold this execute properly, this really is the extent of my question? 
    preg_match($i, $string);
```

Comment: You're more likely to get your questions answered if you accept some of the answers to your old questions

Comment: ah, I didn't know you could do that.  Platform is php. I'll go back and run through them now.

Comment: have you tried what you want to do? Quite often the answer to "will this work?" is to simply try it and see. If it doesn't work, the error message may tell you enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes your right, I should have done more research on this issue before I asked. After changing the question around I'm pretty sure the  above will work out; will verify when I have an opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are simply strings, so you could store them as such in your database.

Comment: Well I know I can store them, I am just wondeirng how to build regex functions dynamically with php and the fuction in a variable string.

Comment: @adbox Explain what you mean by this and provide some examples, and edit your post with such info.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, the only thing you're missing are delimiters.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is
>   enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric,
>   non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and
>   tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited
>   patterns.

```
/foo bar/
#^[^0-9]$#
+php+
%[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%
```

You could also store the expressions without delimiters and add them later.

Comment: `preg_quote()` is not what you want here.

Comment: No, indeed, not really. But if you wish to store parts of the regex as a string and then inject them into an expression you might need it.

Comment: No, why would you do that?

Comment: Could be numerous reasons. For example you have an array of words you want to match which you inject into a regex. You can't 100% be sure the words do not contain a special character so you escape it.
Anyway, maybe in this particular question preg_quote is not needed, just wanted to give a heads up. I'll remove it from the answer.